# Performance of libraries in practice

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, limitations, tags

I know the official limits and boundaries and I know how to use views and folders to stay under the 5k threshold, but I'm strongly under the impression that in practice the max. number of documents in a library in SharePoint Online is way below 100.000. 
We are also using approx. 5 custom tags per library and 5 content types.
I don't know if that is of any influence. But above 7.000 items things seem to get a lot slower already.
I'm not happy with the idea needing to start creating a lot of extra libraries
I wonder what is the experience IN PRACTICE with SharePoint Online for other admins on this forum with this.

Comment: In practice, it varies by tenant. Also, lookups and broken permission inheritance are going to be your biggest perf hogs, not list size.

Comment: Thanx Derek Gusoff